Based on the sound, what could be wrong with my furnace blower wheel
We notice the furnace runs louder than￼we remembered. I opened the furnace up and I can hear loud metal rattle noise come from the blower. then I took everything apart, and tested the motor, which runs fine, but with the wheels on, the wheel rattles as it shows in the video. Is the wheel out of balance or broken?

Most immediate guess is worn out bearings. Or something being loose.

It's also possible the D shaft is worn to less than a D shaft profile, or the blower cage where it fits onto the D shaft is worn as well.  Had a plastic Trane vent blower go bad where it no longer fit snugly on the motor's D shaft and made a lot of noise, so it's possible you're having the same sort of issue.

Downvoting because the question is about the failure, from wear, of a particular part of a particular appliance.  It isn't translatable to any general case, it doesn't include photos or descriptions of the failed part or what attempts have been made to diagnose it or anything else that would help to determine what's wrong.

Hi @jay613 though rare but this is a general case as there are cases like this on the internet. There is a video link shows the exact symptoms.

It was caused by the two disks in the blower wheel that become loose over time, which is not noticeable to the naked eye, but will vibrate and make that sound at high speed.
People on the internet have done things like drilling many screws between the two disks in the middle to fasten them. But one person mentioned simply hammering with a flathead driver into the gaps between the two disks to fasten the gaps one by one. I have done exactly that and it has worked for me for a week now.
